# XAMPP : MySQL shutdown unexpectedly INNODB warnings

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

Everything was working fine but suddenly MySQL stopped working and shuts down unexpectedly before starting. I tried various solutions based on other stack overflow answers.

1. I deleted `ibdata1` in `C:\xampp\mysql\data` and restarted XAMPP = Not Resolved
2. I deleted all the custom database folders and only kept those that were there initially when installed = Not Resolved

Error Log File Says:

```
2016-02-09 16:47:08 1430 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
160209 16:47:08 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
160209 16:47:08 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101
160209 16:47:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160209 16:47:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160209 16:47:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160209 16:47:08 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160209 16:47:08 [ERROR] Aborting

160209 16:47:08 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: If removed `ibdata1` (not the best idea, but it's done) did you also remove `ib_logfile*`?  Rename out of the way is preferable over deleting.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes actually I renamed those files to .bkp and not deleted. Yes I did rename ib_logfile*s as well. New were created but getting same error. Last time I had to reinstall to fix this problem, but here again I am getting same problem after few days of installing xampp.

Comment: Ah, well, that's good.  It seems strange to me that `[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101` is not immediately preceded by an error message or code, and doesn't contain one itself.  Can we assume you have sufficient free disk space?  What version of MySQL server is this? (I'm looking at the source code to try to find where this error is generated and have not spotted it, so far.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am using XAMPP version 5.6.15. Disk space is not an issue, 300GB free space in C Drive. This problem I am facing with XAMPP for last few weeks. Reinstalling does the trick but same problem occurs after few days.

Comment: Okay, but this section of the log is only about your attempt to recover from a problem, and doesn't give any hints as to what went wrong originally. Also, I'll check the 5.6.15 source.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_log_files_in_group`?  It should be only 2, but it smells like it is over 100.

Comment: @RickJames where do I find this `innodb_log_files_in_group` ? is it inside any .ini file or somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking on different forums I found no solution. I had to reinstall and it happened again. Then I came across an answer somewhere on stackoverflow, that not starting xampp as administrator and shutting it down causes mysql to corrupt over time. So go to properties and make sure it will always run as administrator. Hope others finding the reason behind this get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer!

Comment: I found a lot of solutions to this problem saying just "run as administrator" not weighting the security repercussions, for the same issue I'm able to run Mysql on the command line as unprivileged why? that is a good question too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to resolve this issue is, to **remove** below **two files** from **MySql setup directory**.

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile0 

/usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. Removing these files in C:\xampp\mysql\data\ solved the problem:

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
ibdata1
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade the Mariadb in Xammp and after that the xammp can't start the database but If remove the file from xampp directory xampp\mysql\data\ :

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
ibdata1
```

you can start it again!